# symfony2 build form entity oneToMany

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, entity, builder

I am learning symfony framework and have a big problem.

I have two database table: category (primary key: categoryid) and product (primary key: productid and foreign key: category_categoryid).

In the Controller add a "editAction" for edit the product data (include field category_categoryid) and save in DB.

The form must contain a categories dropdownlist for classify the product.

The code:

Relation in ORM yml

Entity: Product
...

```
manyToOne:
 category:
  targetEntity: Category
   inversedBy: products
   joinColumn:
    name: category_categoryid 
    referencedColumnName: categoryid
```

Entity: Category
...

```
oneToMany:
 products:
  targetEntity: Product
   mappedBy: category
```

Form/Type
ProductType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
...

$builder->add('category_categoryid', 'entity',
array('class' => 'SysCatalogoBundle:Category',

'property' => 'name',));

...
}
```

ProductController

```
public function editAction(Request $request)
{
$id = 1;
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$products= $em->getRepository('SysCatalogoBundle:Product')->find($id);
$form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $products);


...
}
```

The view renderize a form with the list of categories in  element, but not selected product category (saved in DB). I prove use type "query_builder" but didn't work, also tried with class "new Category" didn't work eather. If i use "choice" type with simpler array (array(1,2,3)) the category is selected.

Which could be the problem? The relation of ORM Entities?
I follow the official symfony2 documentation.

I appreciate your help very very much! (sorry my english)

Comment: If you debug (or `var_dump`) is `$products->category` valid in your edit controller action?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the orm mapping in your form builder.  Try changing Form/Type ProductType to this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) { 
...

    $builder->add('category', 'entity', array());

... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution for this is pretty much covered in Symfony's official docu. 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information